# Stripe Element doesn't load in Android WebView

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.js

My Stripe Element doesn't load (not showing) in Android WebView during live mode, it work during test.

Here is some code :

*HTML*

```
<form action="stripe_element.php" method="post" id="payment-form">
 <div class="form-row">
  <hr/>
  <div id="card-element">
   <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
  </div>
  <!-- Used to display form errors -->
  <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
 </div>
 <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

*JS*

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_live_XXXXXXXXXXX');
var elements = stripe.elements();
var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    }
  };

// Create an instance of the card Element
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style, hidePostalCode: true});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the card-element <div>
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle form submission
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
     if (result.error) {
       // Inform the user if there was an error
       var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
       errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
     } else {
       stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
     }
   });
});
```

Check the first line of my JS code : `var stripe = Stripe('pk_live_XXXXXXXXXXX');`, it's my publishable live key.
If I use `var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXX');`, my publishable test key, the test work fine.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: A more detailed description, perhaps with some code / images, might help assessing the problem.

Comment: @sancho.s check my answer

Comment: What errors are you getting in webview in live mode?

Comment: What you posted as an answer is better placed as part of the question.
In addition what does "doesn't load" mean? What happens? Is there any error message? Again, you have to help others help you. It is hard for anyone to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Itz Maybe due the HTTPS issue in webview android API
try to add this overloaded method

```
 @Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
}
```

Alternative:
instead, u can try a native XML form to create charges in stripe Refer this 
Document:
https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android

sample project:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/tree/master/example